How to maintain vertex connection during rotation animation between two triangles in RealityKit?

I'm working with RealityKit and trying to create an animation where a red triangle rotates while maintaining contact with a black triangle at their shared vertices. Here's my current code:
struct TestView: View {

var body: some View {
    RealityView {content in
        
    
        var material = PhysicallyBasedMaterial()
        material.baseColor = SimpleMaterial.BaseColor(tint: .pink1)
        material.faceCulling = .none
        
        var firstDescription = MeshDescriptor(name: "firstDescription")
        firstDescription.positions = MeshBuffers.Positions(
          [[-1, -1, 0], [1, -1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
        )
        
        firstDescription.primitives = .triangles([0, 1, 2])
        let firstEntity = ModelEntity(
           mesh: try! .generate(from: [firstDescription]),
           materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .black, isMetallic: false)]
        )
        firstEntity.scale = .init(x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0.1)
        content.add(firstEntity)
        
        
        var secondDescription = MeshDescriptor(name: "secondDescription")
        secondDescription.positions = MeshBuffers.Positions(
          [[-1, -1, 0], [0, -3, 0], [1, -1, 0]]
        )
        
        secondDescription.primitives = .triangles([0, 1, 2])
        let secondEntity = ModelEntity(
           mesh: try! .generate(from: [secondDescription]),
           materials: [material]
        )
        secondEntity.scale = .init(x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0.1)
        
        secondEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        secondEntity.components[InputTargetComponent.self] = InputTargetComponent()
        content.add(secondEntity)
    }
    .gesture(TapGesture()
            .targetedToAnyEntity()
            .onEnded({ tap in
                let tapentity = tap.entity
                
                var transform = tapentity.transform
                transform.translation = [0, -0.2, 0.001]
                transform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: -.pi, axis: [1,0,0])
            
                let animationDefinition = FromToByAnimation(to: transform,
                                                            bindTarget: .transform)
                let animationViewDefinition = AnimationView(source: animationDefinition,
                                                            delay: 0,
                                                            speed: 0.5)
                let animationResource = try! AnimationResource.generate(with: animationViewDefinition)
                tapentity.playAnimation(animationResource)
            }))
}

}
Is there a way to define an animation that maintains the vertex connection between both triangles during the rotation? Maybe using a different animation approach or calculating intermediate positions?
